# Binary Erosion coming up black

Tags: c++, image-processing, image-morphology

I'm trying to implement the morphological erosion operation for a binary image. Everything is black after I run it though. I've set my structuring element (int array element) to a 3x3 square.

```
const int radius = 1;
int element[(radius * 2 + 1)*(radius * 2 + 1)] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
int iBitPerPixel = pDoc->_bmp->bitsperpixel;
int iWidth = pDoc->_bmp->width;
int iHeight = pDoc->_bmp->height;
BYTE *pImg = pDoc->_bmp->point;
int Wp = iWidth;

BYTE copy[319*240*10];

int r = (3 * iWidth) % 6;
int p = (6 - r) % 6;
Wp = 3 * iWidth + p;



for (int i = iHeight - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    for (int j = 0; j < iWidth; j++)
    {
        copy[i*Wp + j * 3] = pImg[i*Wp + j * 3];
        pImg[i*Wp + j * 3] = 0;
        pImg[i*Wp + j * 3 + 1] = 0;
        pImg[i*Wp + j * 3 + 2] = 0;
    }

bool fit = true;
for (int i = iHeight - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    for (int j = 0; j < iWidth; j++)
    {
        for (int x = radius; x <= -radius; x--)
            for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
            {
                if (i + x < 0 || i + x >= iHeight|| j + y < 0) continue;
                if (element[(x + radius)*radius + y + radius] == 1 && copy[(i + x)*Wp + (j + y) * 3] == 0)
                {
                    fit = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        if (fit)
            for (int x = radius; x <= -radius; x--)
                for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
                    pImg[(i + x)*Wp + (j + y) * 3] = 255;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You make two the error in this loop: `for (int x = radius; x <= -radius; x--)`. You initialize `x` at 1, and then the condition is `x <= -1`, so you never enter the loop.

Annex:

1. Why your two loops on `i` and `j`do not go in the same direction?
2. I don't understand what you want to do in the test `if (element[(x + radius)*radius + y + radius] == 1 && copy[(i + x)*Wp + (j + y) * 3] == 0)`. The principle of an erosion is to keep the minimum value within a given neighborhood (defined by the structuring element).
3. Except if you DO want to implement the methods by yourself in order to understand how the basic algorithm works, else you will find highly optimized mathematical morphology methods in the [SMIL](https://smil.cmm.mines-paristech.fr/doc/index.html) library. There is also OpenCV.